# Exporting SVG from Illustrator with stroke as an SVG attribute

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, export, javascript

I have created a simple chevron icon in Illustrator and now exporting it as an SVG. Technically, it's just a path with a 2pt round brush stroke.

When I export it as an SVG with the stroke applied I get the following markup:

```
<svg id="F-Chevron" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 9 16">
  <title>Icons</title>
  <g id="Right">
    <path d="M7.79,5.71l7,7V11.29l-7,7a1,1,0,0,0,1.41,1.41l7-7a1,1,0,0,0,0-1.41l-7-7A1,1,0,0,0,7.79,5.71Z" transform="translate(-7.5 -4)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

When I export the layer without the stroke I get this, which is my desired result, but without a stroke attribute.

```
<svg id="F-Chevron" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 7 14">
  <title>Icon</title>
  <g id="Right">
    <polyline points="0 0 7 7 0 14" style="fill: none"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Is it possible to have the stroke applied within Illustrator but export as an SVG to get something like the below? (Note the attributes on the SVG tag)

```
<svg id="F-Chevron" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 7 14" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000">
  <title>Icon</title>
  <g id="Right">
    <polyline points="0 0 7 7 0 14" style="fill: none"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Any help is much appreciated, can't find a way around it unless I apply the strokes manually in each icon SVG file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue here was that I had created a custom brush stroke, which I'm assuming doesn't play well with SVG exports. This was fixed by using a round capped basic stroke and manually setting the stroke width.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the stroke attributes to the SVG you want...

```
<svg id="F-Chevron" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 7 14" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000">
  <title>Icon</title>
  <g id="Right" stroke-width="1" stroke="blue">
    <polyline points="0 0 7 7 0 14" style="fill: none;"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Of course I could, but as I already mentioned in the post I didn't want to manually add the stroke every time I saved a single icon. Unless I wrote a script for it but it would just turn out messy and become a lengthy export process.